# Setting the default value of an Access 97 text field to an empty string

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

Using DAO and VB6 I try to set the default value of an access 97 text field to an empty string (rather than Null) thus:

```
Dim newField as DAO.Field
Set newField = myTablelDef.CreateField("NewField", dbText, 10)
newField.DefaultValue=""
```

However, this is interpreted as Null and new records for which the NewField is not specified get Null as their value in stead of an empty string. If I change the value to, say, "Default" this is reflected in new records, so the code in itself is correct. I know that it IS possible to assign an empty string rather than Null to a Text field, so how is it done?

Comment: I don't think replacing NULL with ZLS gets you much further forward. Instead, consider modelling missing data either implicitly (e.g. the absence of a row in the `Salaries` table for `employee_number = '52644'` means they do not have a salary for whatever reason) or explicitly (e.g. the presence of a row in the `Unsalaried` table for `employee_number = '52644'` means they are known to have no salary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
txtFieldone.AllowZeroLength = True
txtFieldone.DefaultValue = """"""
```

Not sure what's going on here, but I tested it with a query on = "" and it returns the correct records!

Comment: Also shows up in Access design view with "" in the Default Value

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the `newField.AllowZeroLength = True`.

In Access97 all text & memo fields have this set to false.  In 2000 & beyond it's the opposite.

Here's a way to [set them all to true via code](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-09.html).

Comment: This answer sounded very promising, but the AllowZeroLength was already set to True. Setting it to False does not help either. I expected an error at inserting a record without the NewField being specfified, but not so.

Comment: I just found another reference that states in order for this to work you also have to set the Required Property for the field to Yes..... Give it a shot....

Comment: Now I DO get the errors ;-) When I make the field required Access refuses to accept records for which the NewField is not set, while I want Access to insert empty strings by default. Some more hunting by myself seems to reveal that what I want is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that setting it = "" does not work. Set AllowZeroLength = true, and on each insert, set that field = "". Not perfect, but it will work.